# More concise way of adding a class to elements stored in an array?

Tags: javascript

Im creating 3 elements and later in my code I need to add the same class to each of them. Currently Im doing it like this and its working fine:

```
const item1 = document.createElement('div');
const item2 = document.createElement('div');
const item3 = document.createElement('div');

// later on in the code

function addClasses() {
  item1.classList.add('item--animating');
  item2.classList.add('item--animating');
  item2.classList.add('item--animating');
}
```

However it seems un DRY to have this repetition. Is there a shorter way of writing this?

I could create an array of items and then loop through the array adding the class to each one, but im my opinion this would be counter productive in terms of making my code concise and easy to reason about.

Comment: `[item1, item1, item3].forEach(x => x.classList.add('item--animating'))` If they are under same parent, you can add this class to parent and update the CSS accordingly

Comment: @Rajesh, but why downgrade to `className +=`? This has issues with spacing classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Rajesh's answer:

```
const item1 = document.createElement('div');
const item2 = document.createElement('div');
const item3 = document.createElement('div');
const allItems = [item1, item2, item3];

allItems.forEach(x => x.classList.add('item--animating'));
```